# How can I add same item to cart but only increase quantity

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to add same item into cart and trying to make it only increase the quantity but whenever I added item to cart it will show 2 same items.

Here is my reducer:

```
import {
    ADD_PRODUCT_BASKET,
    GET_NUMBERS_BASKET,
    LOADING,
    SUCCESS
} from '../actions/type';

const initialState = {
    products: [],
    loading: false,
    basketNumbers: 0,
    cartCost: 0,
    numbers: 0,
    inCart: false
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case LOADING:
            return {
                ...state,
                products: [],
                    loading: true,
                    err: ''
            };

        case SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                products: action.payload,
                    loading: false,
                    err: ''
            };
        case ADD_PRODUCT_BASKET:
            let numbers = (state.numbers += 1);
            let inCart = (state.inCart = true);
            let product = state.products;
            return {
                ...state,
                basketNumbers: state.basketNumbers + 1,
                    cartCost: state.cartCost + action.payload.price,
                    product: product.push(action.payload),
                    numbers: numbers,
                    inCart: inCart
            };
        case GET_NUMBERS_BASKET:
            return {
                ...state
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

and here is my cart:

```
function Cart({ basketProps }) {
  const nf = new Intl.NumberFormat();
  let productsInCart = [];

  if (basketProps.inCart) {
    productsInCart = basketProps.products;
  } else {
    productsInCart = [];
  }

  let productQuantity = 1;

    {productsInCart.map((product, i) => (
      <ProductInfo key={i}>
        <Infor>
          <Image src={product.img_url1} />
        </Infor>
        <Infor>
          <ProductTitle>{product.title}</ProductTitle>
          <ProductPrice>
            <ProductQuantity>{productQuantity} x </ProductQuantity>
            {nf.format(product.price)} vnd
          </ProductPrice>
        </Infor>
      </ProductInfo>
    ))}
}
```

How can I make the quality increase instead of like add a new item into my cart?

Here is my github project if you want to look over my code:

https://github.com/nathannewyen/the-beuter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to hold a counter of each product. Now you just keep `push`ing products into the array.

Instead of

```
product: product.push(action.payload),
```

You should do sth like

```
let products = [...state.product];
let foundProduct = products.find(prod => prod.title === action.payload.title);

if (foundProduct) {
  foundProduct.quantity++;
} else {
 action.payload.quantity = 1;
 products.push(action.payload);
}
```

and then

```
 return {
          ...state,
          basketNumbers: state.basketNumbers + 1,
          cartCost: state.cartCost + action.payload.price,
          product: products,
          numbers: numbers,
          inCart: inCart
         };
```

I don't know what are these other properties `basketNumbers` and `numbers` but I guess they are all related to `product` array, so they can be removed.